# ExecuteNonQuery() ERROR -> The conversion of the nvarchar value '3955811801' overflowed an int column.

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, executenonquery

My code is as shown below :

```
using (SqlConnection _conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DarmanConnectionString"].ToString()))
{
    using (SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.sp_Noskheh_SumOfTotalPay", _conn))
    {
        _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        _cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Co_ID", int.Parse(Session["Co_ID"].ToString())));

        _cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
        _cmd.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        _conn.Open();
        _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Int64 result = Int64.Parse(_cmd.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Value.ToString());
        lblSumTotalPayShow.Text = result.ToString();

            _conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

my SP is like this :

```
create Procedure [dbo].[sp_Noskheh_SumOfTotalPay]
    @Co_ID int
As    
    -----------------
    Declare @Sum nvarchar(50)
    -----------------    
BEGIN
    Select @Sum = convert(nvarchar(50), SUM(TotalPay))
    From Noskheh
    Where (Co_ID = @Co_ID)

    Return @Sum
END
```

and the error is in line (_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();):

Error:

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The conversion of
>   the nvarchar value '3955811801' overflowed an int column. The
>   'sp_Noskheh_SumOfTotalPay' procedure attempted to return a status of
>   NULL, which is not allowed. A status of 0 will be returned instead.

Would you please help me to figure out this problem?

Comment: What is the datatype of Noskheh.Co_ID? Does @Co_ID = 3955811801?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to convert a nvarchar value to a `int`

[The `Return` statement must be an integer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx)

Try changing your approach and in your Stored Proc do

`Select @Sum` instead of `return @sum`

Then instead of using `ExecuteNonQuery` use `ExecuteScalar`

```
String result = (String)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
lblSumTotalPayShow.Text = result.ToString();
```

Comment: can u expain more // in my sp Select @Sum exists // what exactly should i change in sp and code behind

Answer (score 3):

1. <strike>Change @Co_ID to bigint. 3955811801 is higher then 2^31-1</strike>
2. The SUM is greater than 2^31-1. The RETURN tries to convert it to int and fails.
   Use an OUTPUT parameters or just return a recordset.

Like this

```
create Procedure [dbo].[sp_Noskheh_SumOfTotalPay]
 @Co_ID int,
 @Sum nvarchar(50) OUTPUT --or bigint?
As

BEGIN
 Select 
  @Sum = convert(nvarchar(50), SUM(TotalPay))
 From Noskheh
  Where
  (Co_ID = @Co_ID)
END
```

or

```
create Procedure [dbo].[sp_Noskheh_SumOfTotalPay]
 @Co_ID int
As

BEGIN
 Select 
  SUM(TotalPay) AS SumTotalPay
 From Noskheh
  Where
  (Co_ID = @Co_ID)
END
```

Comment: You can change all of your parameters in your SP to bigint or varchar as a temporary workaround.

Comment: the first way not helped // i can not use the second way because of my c# classes //

Comment: You should not use return for user data anyway. You have to use one of the 2 methods I mentioned There is **no** other way to get data back

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is not the @Co_ID as others indicate, then maybe the `SUM(TotalPay)` might be equal to your 3.9 billion value.  if the TotalPay column is an integer, the SUM is integer before converting to varchar.